# jquery multidimensional

Tags: php, jquery

I am cloning the last row in table but i need unique multidimensional name for each input...

```
    <tr>
<td><input type="text" name='input[1][Name]'></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name='input[1][address]'></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name='input[1][contactInfo]'></input></td>
</tr>
```

next row should be

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name='input[2][Name]'></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name='input[2][address]'></input></td>
<td><input type="text" name='input[2][contactInfo]'></input></td>
</tr>
```

...........
jquery

```
  $(".alternativeRow").click(function(){
i=2;
                $("table tr:last").clone().find("input").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr({
                        'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
                        'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
                        'value': ''               
                    });
                }).end().appendTo("table");
                i++;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

For multidimensional name no need to give explicit index to the names. directly you can write like this.

```
<input type="text" name='input[][Name]'></input>
```

This will automatically take the index no when you receive the form data on server side.

Comment: Its gives me following output on server when using the multidimensional name like this input[][name], input[][address]..[input] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (    [Name] => sh           )

            [1] => Array
                (   [address] => pu          )

            [2] => Array
                (   [contactInfo] => 123     )

      
            [3] => Array
                (  [Name] => sf              )

            [4] => Array
                (  [address] => ds           )

            [5] => Array
                ( [contactInfo] => 234       )

        )

Comment: and if i use <input type="text" name='input[1][Name]'></input> then i got only one row i.e. last row of table after submitting the form..

Comment: Okay thats correct, My bad try this this will group your data. I'm hoping its as address and giving index address as <input type="text" name='input[address][][Name]'></input> Then you will get some thing like this "Address" => [0] => [name] = "sh", [address] = "pu".... "Address" => [1] => [name] = "sh1", [address] = "pu1"...

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".alternativeRow").click(function(){
i=2;
                $("table tr:last").clone().find("input").each(function() {
                   this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(){
                        return '[' + i +']';
                    });
                })
                .end().appendTo("table");
                i++;
      });
```